# Convertir sql a Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
 Select Curso.* from Curso left join AlumnoCurso on Curso.id = AlumnoCurso.Curso_id where AlumnoCurso.Curso_id is null
```

Amigos tengo esta Consulta pero no he logrado saber como pasarla a linq o a una expression lambda Me ayudan por favor?

en el momento tengo esto, ya que al usar dos interacciones del dbContext me generaba un error, ahora hago esto pero no me trae los datos.

```
cursos = ctx.Curso.ToList();

                    var Query = from curso in cursos
                                 join alumno in ctx.AlumnoCurso on curso.id equals alumno.Curso_id into g
                                 where g.DefaultIfEmpty() == null
                                 select curso;
                    cursos = Query.ToList();
```

he logrado hacerlo pero con Expression lambda hay una posible solución con LINQ?

```
 var cursos_tomados = ctx.AlumnoCurso.Where(x => x.Alumno_id == Alumno_id)
                                                        .Select(x => x.Curso_id)
                                                        .ToList();
                    cursos = ctx.Curso.Where(x => !cursos_tomados.Contains(x.id)).ToList();
```

Comment: estas utilizando entity framework ? entiendo quieres listar solo los cursos que tengan un alumno asignado, no?

Comment: Tengo una relación con alumno curso y necesito listar solo los cursos disponibles en un dropdowlist, es decir un alumno tiene algunos cursos ya asignados necesito mostrar solo los que quedan disponibles. no una lista de todos sabiendo que ya tiene algunos asignados y si utilizo entity Framework

Comment: lo que noto es que usas la misma variable dos veces, cuando realices el Query.ToList() asignalo a otra variable, es mas porque no integras el ctx.Curso.ToList() en el linq, porque lo sacas fuera usando el ToList(), eso no es necesario

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a reescribir el código con lambdas a código sin lambdas (:

No cometas el error de aseverar que la presencia de lambdas implica la ausencia de expresiones LINQ. Recuerda que los métodos de extensión `Select`, `Where`, entre otros, son todos parte de LINQ; el gran detalle es que en un caso se pueden utilizar estos métodos en un estilo parecido a SQL y en otro caso se utilizan como una llamada en cascada de los distintos métodos de extensión. Cualquiera que sea el caso, el código MSIL generado al compilar es prácticamente el mismo, el cual se expresa como una llamada en cascada de los distintos métodos de extensión.

Tomando como base el código LINQ con lambdas, a como está en la pregunta:

```
var cursos_tomados = ctx.AlumnoCurso.Where(x => x.Alumno_id == ((Alumno_id)))
                      .Select(x => x.Curso_id)
                      .ToList();
cursos = ctx.Curso.Where(x => !cursos_tomados.Contains(x.id)).ToList();
```

Tal y como está escrito, `Alumno_id` (entre paréntesis dobles) es una variable cuyo valor está previamente definido. Esto no se aprecia en la consulta SQL original, ¿tal vez se te pasó por alto?

Según veo, el objetivo es primero obtener todos los id de cursos que el `Alumno_id` tiene asignado. Luego, obtener todos los cursos que el `Alumno_id` **no** tiene asignados (mediante una resta de conjuntos).

Por ponerlo de una manera más comprensible, lo que se desea es: dado un `Alumno_id` correspondiente a un `Alumno`, obtener todos los `Cursos` que **no** están asignados a ese alumno. Si el objetivo que persigues **no** es el que he descrito hasta ahora deja un comentario para saber más precisamente lo que deseas lograr.

La primera instrucción de la expresión LINQ anterior se puede reescribir como:

```
var cursosTomadosIds = (from cursoTomado in ctx.AlumnoCurso
                       where cursoTomado.Alumno_id == Alumno_id
                       select cursoTomado.Curso_id).ToList();
```

Y la segunda instrucción se puede reescribir como:

```
var cursosNoTomados = (from curso in ctx.Curso
                      where !cursosTomadosIds.Contains(curso.id)).ToList();
```

Puedes combinar ambas expresiones LINQ con ayuda de la instrucción `let`:

```
var cursosNoTomados = (from curso in ctx.Curso
                      let cursosTomadosIds = (from cursoTomado in ctx.AlumnoCurso
                                             where cursoTomado.Alumno_id == Alumno_id
                                             select cursoTomado.Curso_id).ToList()
                      where !cursosTomadosIds.Contains(curso.id)).ToList();
```

En este caso particular, la expresión combinada es mucho menos eficiente que las expresiones por separado, ya que la expresión `let` es re-evaluada para cada entrada de la enumeración generada por el código LINQ. Te recomiendo **no** utilices la expresión LINQ combinada.

Un `left join` también funciona. Puedes definirlo como:

```
var query = from curso in ctx.Curso
            join alumnoCurso in (from ac in ctx.AlumnoCurso
                                 where ac.Alumno_id == ((Alumno_id))
                                 select ac)
                             on curso.id equals alumnoCurso.Curso_id into g
            where !g.Any()
            select curso;
```

Nota la presencia de una sub-consulta que contiene `((Alumno_id))` en el código anterior. `Alumno_id` (entre paréntesis dobles) debe ser una variable cuyo valor está previamente definido.

Cualquier intriga, ¡no dudes en dejar un comentario!

Answer (score 1):

Añado un método extensor para LeftsJoins en LinQ, y el ejemplo de como utilizarlo, por si le vale a alguien:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> 
    LeftJoin<TSource, TInner, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                  IEnumerable<TInner> inner, 
                                                  Func<TSource, TKey> pk, 
                                                  Func<TInner, TKey> fk, 
                                                  Func<TSource, TInner, TResult> result)
{
    IEnumerable<TResult> _result = Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();

    _result = from s in source
          join i in inner
          on pk(s) equals fk(i) into joinData
          from left in joinData.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select result(s, left);

    return _result;
}  



var resultJoint = Person.BuiltPersons().LeftJoin(                    /// Source Collection
                    Address.BuiltAddresses(),                        /// Inner Collection
                    p => p.IdAddress,                                /// PK
                    a => a.IdAddress,                                /// FK
                    (p, a) => new { MyPerson = p, MyAddress = a })   /// Result Collection
                .Select(a => new
                {
                    Name             = a.MyPerson.Name,
                    Age              = a.MyPerson.Age,
                    PersonIdAddress  = a.MyPerson.IdAddress,
                    AddressIdAddress = (a.MyAddress != null ? a.MyAddress.IdAddress : -1),
                    Street           = (a.MyAddress != null ? a.MyAddress.Street    : "Null-Value")
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

En linq puede implementar el `left join`

[Cómo: Realizar operaciones de combinación externa izquierda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/bb397895.aspx)

podria ser algo como esto

```
 var query = from curso in dbcontext.Curso
            join alumno in dbcontext.AlumnoCurso on curso.id equals alumno.Curso_id into g
            where g.DefaultIfEmpty() == null
            select curso;
```

Comment: Leandro, Me sale este error no logro comprenderlo muy bien, Información adicional: Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Model.AlumnoCurso, Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Comment: si estas usando EF la tabla intermedia en una relacion muchos a muchos no se modela, solo tendrias que tener las entidades Curso y Alumno, la tabla intermedia no deberia estar en tu modelo ya que esta se refleja en propiedades de lista en las entidades. O sea el entidad Curso tendra una propiedad List<Alumno> y al entidad Alumno tendra una propiedad List<Curso>

Comment: Pero debería modelarla, ya que hay varios alumnos con diferentes cursos asignados y de echo notas definitivas de esos curso, igual la relacion de muchos a muchos la tengo un esta tabla intermedia y cada una osea curso y alumno crean una   ICollection<AlumnoCurso> AlumnoCurso, busque el error y me salia algo referente con que contexto de datos, que no lo podía usar dos veces.

Comment: en la entidad AlumnoCurso estas definiendo datos ? podrias editar la pregunta y poner el codigo linq que estas ejecutando

Comment: Ya logre hacerlo pero quisiera una posible solución con linq lo hice con expression lambda

Comment: @LeandroTuttini `where g.DefaultIfEmpty() == null` siempre se evaluará como `false`, ya que `DefaultIfEmpty()` jamás devuelve `null` como resultado. Debido a esto, `query` jamás contendrá elementos.